# Writing contents of list to single csv column

Tags: python, list, csv

I am trying to write the contents of a list to a single column in a csv file. While I have done this in the past, I am not able to get this script to work. Instead I all of the columns filled instead of the rows

```
#getting values for p vlue of 1%-100%        
a = [numpy.arange(.01,1.01,.01)]
for i in a:
    with open("GFOLD_Hisat2.csv", 'wb') as file3:
        filewriter = csv.writer(file3)
        filewriter.writerow(score(list1, list2, i))
```

Where score() is a function that outputs an integer

Any thoughts on what I should modify?

Comment: Well what are list1 and list2? are they actual lists, because that changes things? Also have you tried taking 'val' out of its brackets, not sure you need those

Comment: You should modify your question to show what are `list1` and `list2`, what your desired output is, and what your actual output is.

Comment: I modified the code a bit to make it simpler.

Comment: Please post a short, complete program that actually demonstrates your question (the current sample generates: `_csv.Error: sequence expected`). Please read [mcve] to see how and why such a program is important.

Comment: Hang on .. `a = [numpy.arange(.01,1.01,.01)]` this results in a list containing a list (actually an `ndarray`). So `for i in a` just gives you one iteration.

Comment: And you want `linspace`, not `arrange`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ignoring the questions of what `list1` and `list2` are (they are irrelevant if `score()` returns a single integer), I think the problem lies in your loop structure.

Instead of

```
for i in a:
    with open("GFOLD_Hisat2.csv", 'wb') as file3:
        filewriter = csv.writer(file3)
        filewriter.writerow(score(list1, list2, i))
```

You probably want

```
with open("GFOLD_Hisat2.csv", 'wb') as file3:
    filewriter = csv.writer(file3)
    for i in a:
        filewriter.writerow((score(list1, list2, i),))
```

At present you are opening the file and creating a new writer for each value of  `i`. Note that I have turned the result of `score` into a `tuple`.

```
In [8]: a = [1,2,3,4,5]
In [9]: with open('a.csv', 'wt') as f:
    wr = csv.writer(f)
    for i in a:
        wr.writerow((i,))
   ...:         
In [10]: !cat a.csv
1
2
3
4
5
```

I'm also not sure why you are opening the file with `'wb'`

As Rob points out, you can just use a comprehension - avoiding the loop completely. My answer is focused on explaining the  mistake in your existing code.

Also, if your output file is really only going to contain a single column there's little reason to use a `csv.writer`. Simply do the following

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
b = [score(list1, list2, i) for i in a]
with open('a.csv','wt') as f:
    f.writelines('\n'.join(map(str,b))
```

Comment: This still won't work: `.writerow()` takes an iterable, but `score()` apparently returns a single `int`.

Comment: Yup, still outputting the contents of the list in columns instead of rows.

Comment: See my comment on the question about `a = [numpy.arange(.01,1.01,.01)]`

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the order of the file opening and the loop:

```
a = [numpy.arange(.01,1.01,.01)]

with open("GFOLD_Hisat2.csv", 'wb') as file3:
    filewriter = csv.writer(file3)
    for i in a:
        filewriter.writerow(score(list1, list2, i))
```